# Unexpected values in variables at the end

Tags: javascript

I was trying my hand at node.js and I noticed a strange (to me) behavior in my code. Supposing it was due to my inexperience with async coding, I tried to replicate in pure (sync)  javascript, but with the same result.
Below, my code:

```
function AddCurrWeek(agenda) {
    try {
        agenda["Tue"].push("Some event");
        return agenda;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

function Initialize() {
    var new_week = { "Sun": [], "Mon": [], "Tue": [], "Wed": [], "Thu": [], "Fri": [], "Sat": [] };
    try {
        return new_week;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

function Main() {
    try {
        var aPrec, aCurr
        var aInit = Initialize();
        aPrec = aInit;
// after this line < aPrec > is used no more.

        // adding some data to < aInit > saving into a new variable:
        aCurr = AddCurrWeek(aInit);

        if (aCurr != aPrec ) {
          console.log("Save changes...");
          // but it is never different!!!!
        }
        console.log("> aCurr:", aCurr);
        console.log("> aPrec:", aPrec);
// At the end, < aCurr > and < aPrec > share the same value!!!!
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

Main()
```

Please, could someone tell me why at the end `aCurr` and `aPrec` share he same value and how to avoid this?
Thanks in advance.
Denis

Comment: You should try to find a better title for the question, the current one is not very explicit ;)

Comment: I don't understand why you would expect `aCurr` and `aPrec` to be different. I mean the code literally comes down to `let a = {}, b = a; a === b;`, just that you put a ton of verbose code around it.

Comment: Since AddCurrWeek modifies and returns its input instance, both variables point to the same object, this is the expected behaviour

Comment: Thank you Matt for having made me think about "passing/pointing" (sorry for my bat title: it is not clear because my mind was not clear). So, I had to  "clone" my var instead of "copy" it. So simple now... But not without your suggestion. updated like this: 
'''
function AddCurrWeek(agenda) {
   ...
   var newAgenda = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(agenda))
   return newAgenda;
}

Answer (score 1):

The variable names are just pointers to the actual data structure, which you only create once with `var aInit = Initialize();`

`aPrec = aInit;` doesn't make a copy of the contents of data structure, it just says that `aPrec` should point to the same data structure as `aInit`.

Notice how the output of `console.log("> aCurr:", aCurr); console.log("> aPrec:", aPrec);` both contain "Tue: [ 'Some event' ]"? This is your clue that `agenda["Tue"].push("Some event");` is operating on a single data structure, since the change is applied to `aCurr` as well as `aPrec`.